# Error using Alert Dialog

Tags: ios5, xcode4, uialertview

Receiving "No visible @interface for UIAlertView declares the selector 'message:delegate:otherButtonTitles'".  I'm trying to set an 2 button alert dialog to show after the user chooses an image.  I have in the .h file UIAlertDelegate. Here is the image picking code with the alert dialog:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImage *originalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(originalImage);
    NSString* imageName = @"yourPhoto.png";
    NSString* paths = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* fullPathToFile = [paths stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO];

UIAlertView *dir;
dir = [[[UIAlertView alloc]
        message:@"Choose the direction."
        delegate:self
        otherButtonTitles:@"Left",@"Right",nil];
[dir show];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The error show on the line "dir = [[UIAlertView alloc].  Can anyone help me out on why I'm getting this error and how to fix it?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figured out.  It seems you must have the message:@"string" and the CancelButtonTitle:@"string" in the alert dialog.